# NoMethodError in controller that has methods defined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nomethoderror, actioncontroller

I finished implementing and testing a controller, then switched back and forth between Git branches and did some merges here and there, etc.
Now I'm unable to use the methods I've defined for the controller, and also very confused, as I'm getting `NoMethodError` when trying to call them.

Added an edit and solution at the end of the post.

---

Using Rails version 5.2.3 -
Here I've got my controller defined: `app/controllers/paypal_access_token_controller.rb`:

```
class PaypalAccessTokenController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_admin!, only: [:show]

  def njurf
    puts "#######################"
    puts "why can't i call these methods dangit"
    puts "#######################"
  end

  def show
    # doesn't really matter
  end

  def update
    # doesn't really matter either
    # no syntax errors, I promise
  end
end
```

I'd like the `update` method to be called when I start the Rails application.
I added `PaypalAccessToken.update()` to the file `config/environments/development.rb` - this worked.
Now that I've implemented stuff in other seemingly unrelated parts of the application, I can't call on methods from this controller anymore.

I removed the line from `config/environments/development.rb` so that I could run the Rails console and added the `njurf` method to the controller. From the console, I tried calling `PaypalAccessTokenController.njurf`, and `PaypalAccessTokenController.update`, but both give me the bespoke `NoMethodError`.

Here's some proof of concept

```
Loading development environment (Rails 5.2.3)
irb(main):001:0> PaypalAccessTokenController.update
Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from (irb):1
NoMethodError (undefined method `update' for PaypalAccessTokenController:Class)
irb(main):002:0> PaypalAccessTokenController.update()
Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from (irb):2
NoMethodError (undefined method `update' for PaypalAccessTokenController:Class)
irb(main):003:0> PaypalAccessTokenController.njurf()
Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from (irb):3
NoMethodError (undefined method `njurf' for PaypalAccessTokenController:Class)
```

So the controller class exists, at least, but I don't know why I'm getting this error - nor do I know how to go about fixing it.

Any help would be appreciated.

**edit:** This controller only had routes for the `show` method. I removed this route when I had implemented and tested the `update` method, because I no longer needed/wanted these methods to be accessible via URLs.
This is what made the methods inaccessible from console.

---

**solution:** Either I leave in a route to one of the controller's methods - *or*, like Ricky Spanish and amit_saxena pointed out below, properly declare the methods as class methods.

Thanks for the replies

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the use case for directly calling a controller class method?

Comment: The controller handles a model containing paypal api tokens. It is supposed to just refresh the token once it expires, I've created a recurring job for this which calls on the update method.

Comment: Hi Eirik, `Added an edit and solution at the end of the post.` please don't do that. Add an own answer and remove your (answer)edit from the question instead.

Comment: That sounds like the perfect use case for a service object. I don't know why you would use a controller. Controllers are for handling request-response cycles. But, whatever floats your boat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call it, when you define it with `self`

```
def self.njurf
  puts "#######################"
  puts "why can't i call these methods dangit"
  puts "#######################"
end
```

```
PaypalAccessTokenController.njurf
#######################
why can't i call these methods dangit
#######################
=> nil
```

Answer (score 0):

It might look strange, but are you sure you have defined the proper resources on routes?

Comment: I had one route to the `show` method for testing purposes, and no other routes to that controller. Removing that route seems to have caused the problem.
It's a little strange for me still, that removing the route to `show` would make `update` inaccessible from the rails console.

Comment: You could just add only: parameter to your routes and add show and update there, otherwise, you should really have the routes specified for every function you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access controller methods like that from console as they aren't class methods. You can instead try this:

`PaypalAccessTokenController.new.update`

but that doesn't mean it's going to work (it probably needs `params` to work on), but you will not get a `NoMethodError`. Most probably you messed something in your routes file. You can check the routes using:

`bundle exec rake routes`

which will tell you exactly which route points to which `controller#action` and should give you some pointers about what the problem is. Paste the relevant routes here is you are unable to figure it out. Also pay attention to HTTP method (GET/POST/PATCH). You might be using a GET instead of PATCH and getting the error as a result.